# What is the equivalent of Tridion.ContentManager.TcmUri in the CoreServiceClient DLL?

Tags: core-service, tom.net

The TcmUri class is a handy tool, for example to grab the publication id from a component id.

```
string publicationId = new TcmUri(new TcmUri(componentId).PublicationId, ItemType.Publication);
```

How should we do this when using the CoreServiceClient DLL? Now I use this Tridion.Common dll which contains Tridion.ContentManager.TcmUri, but I feel bad about using part of the TOM.NET API in a non-TOM application.

I know we could do string maipulation to get the publication id from the component id, that would be rebuilding part of the TcmUri class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the CoreService, a TcmUri type will be generated as String by the proxy generator, so in most cases you won't need an actual TcmUri class.

There is the `ICoreService2012.GetTcmUri` method which is documented as returning a `TcmUri`, and the notes state that a String might be generated by the proxy, which indeed is the case.

That all being said, `Tridion.ContentManager.TcmUri` is a handy class to use, so you don't have to do String manipulation on your TCM URI when you need things like the Item ID, Publication ID or Item Type.

Answer (score 6):

You can safely use Tridion.Common.dll in your CoreService apps, this dll has no dependencies on the rest of Tridion and contains (among others) the `TcmUri` class.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the Tridion.Common is designed to have no dependencies. Sounds like the most practical way forward.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, I don't see equivalent class for `Tridion.ContentManager.TcmUri` in coreservice. 
it has a function though, to obtain the Item URI in different Repository contexts.

```
string GetTcmUri(string baseUri, string contextRepositoryUri, System.Nullable<uint> version)
```

Also, you can write your own class for it, exposing properties accordingly using sting manipulations.

Comment: For this to be a useful answer, you'll need to give more information.